# Вызов метода с переменным количеством аргументов Java

Tags: java

Есть ArrayList в который распарсены входящие аргументы:

```
List<String> arr = Parser.spaceSplit(s);
```

Есть класс который имплементит интерфейс с методом вида:

```
void method(String... s){//do something };
```

Как вызвать метод передавая ему в качестве аргументов все входящие аргументы из коллекции arr, заведомо не зная сколько их ?
То есть, например, есть в коллекции 10 полей и в каждом из них соответственно есть строка, как вызвать метод передавая ему все поля, что бы не писать

```
method(arr.get(0),arr.get(1).. и так далее
```

ведь заранее не известно, сколько именно будет полей в коллекции.
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А почему бы вам не превратить список в массив?

Вот так работает:

```
public static void Print(String... args)
{
    for (String s : args)
        System.out.println(s);
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String[] array = { "Cinderella", "Sleeping Beauty" };
    Print(array);
}
```

http://ideone.com/GG7EYJ

Это для случая, если вы не имеете контроля над объектом, реализующим `method`. А если имеете, просто выставьте наружу *две* функции, делов-то!

Comment: Действительно, превратил в массив и делов то. Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 3):

```
..
<x>.method(arr.toArray(new String[arr.size()]));
..
```

Comment: поправил немного..

Comment: Угу, так работает.

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 1):

Капитан Очевидность подсказывает, что стоит создать метод, который принимает в качестве параметра List

Comment: Не могу, интерфейсом ограничено на аргументы вида String...s